# running UVM phases on multiple cores

Tags: multithreading, multicore, uvm

How can we devote the individual phases in UVM like run, elaboration, build etc to run on multiple cores of the system. How can this be done through coding.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, multicore support is something you can't influence through coding. It's something your simulator either has or hasn't. Even if you could, you have the problem that your build, connect, run, etc. phase must execute in sequence.