# Multi-threading in UVM

Tags: multithreading, uvm

How can we incorporate multi-threading in UVM. Are the threads in UVM testbench, the extended UVM components, sequences and the methods between fork and join? 
As far I have searched such multi-threaded testbench will hardly make an impact on making the simulation time faster or the performance better unless the design is partitioned for multiple cores of the hardware. Is that so?

Comment: The UVM testbench should not consume more than 5-10% of the CPU.  The RTL code is usually the simulation bottleneck.  If you really need the performance, simulation is not the right solution.  You probably want to consider using an emulation platform.  Optimizing the testbench may gives you at most 2x speedup, emulation box in simulation acceleration mode easily give you 1000x speedup.

Answer (score 0):

Multi-threading in the context of SystemVerilog/UVM has nothing to do with multicore hardware. While EDA vendors do provide multicore support, it's not something you have any control over through coding.

Also have a look at this question: [running UVM phases on multiple cores](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22296583/running-uvm-phases-on-multiple-cores/22301831#22301831).

On a side note:

HDL simulation is multi-threaded by nature because you have to capture signal updates that happen in parallel. SystemVerilog also allows the user to spawn his own parallel execution threads using the `fork...join` family of construct. UVM itself makes heavy use of this feature to start for example sequences and the run phases of all components in parallel. You can of course also use `fork...join` in your own code to start your own parallel threads if you need.

Another note: I think the terminology for starting threads like this in SV is "**starting parallel processes**".

Comment: Yes I do understand that. Multicore simulation is tool dependent. I would like to understand what multi-threaded UVM testbench would be like? As far as I have searched multi-threaded UVM testbench is related to different threads working on different cores of the hardware. So does that imply that multi-threaded testbench in UVM is just about multi-core simulation?

Comment: Read the answer again: multi-threaded UVM has **nothing** to do with threads on processor cores.

Comment: Please throw some light on a multi-threaded UVM testbench.(multi-core not in consideration). Does multi-threading in UVM means a testbench including extended UVM components, sequences and the methods between fork and join as asked in my 1st question. If yes, then does that imply that a UVM testbench is inherently multi-threaded in nature? If not, then how can multi-threading concept be incorporated in a UVM testbench?

Comment: The multicore support provided by EDA vendors is limited only to RTL and Gate level modules that can be structurally partitioned into mostly independent units that are then simulated in parallel on multiple cores. As far as behavioral SystemVerilog constructs are concerned, and that is what a UVM testbench consists of, the tools can not run such tasks in multicore parallel sense. Note that this is a limitation of SystemVerilog since the language does not define concurrency semantics.

Answer (score 0):

To me, both the question and answer show confusion.  Ahlawat seems to be asking two questions:

(1) isn't a UVM testbench multi-threaded by its nature? and

(2) if not, can multi-threading be introduced into a UVM testbench?

I think the answer given to question #1 confuses matters, because I think the statement that HDL simulation is multi-threaded by nature is incorrect.  HDL simulation tries to model the parallelism in a hardware design, where all the different electronic components are operating in parallel; but, it does not use multi-threading to model this.  Instead, HDL simulators (which are, of course, themselves programs) are, at least traditionally, single-threaded programs.  It is quite possible to model the effects of parallelism in a single threaded program, and that is what HDL simulators do.  Modeling parallelism--which means giving the illusion of things happening at the same time---is not the same as things actually happening at the same time.

Multi-threading means breaking a given program up into multiple programs that are enabled to run simultaneously.  Now, it is up to the operating system whether they actually *do* run simultaneously.

And, the operating system is, in turn, constrained by the processor and memory architecture of the machine.

1. On a multi-core computer, quite likely different threads will run on
   a single core.
2. On a single-core computer, where the core is of the old fashioned
   type without the ability to host, inside itself, multiple threads,
   multi-threading will not, in fact, occur, rather, the different
   threads will be switched in and out as context switches.

Well, now that all that is said, one aspect of the answer given was on the mark, which is that the fork-join constructs, which are not part of UVM per se, rather of Verilog and System Verilog, allow one to, essentially, *tell* the operating system that you want certain code in your testbench to run in separate threads.  But, this is not a property of the UVM library, per se, it is a Verilog / System Verilog construct.

Answer (score 0):

UVM/System verilog/verilog codes are simulated by EDA tools. The language has not defined any keyword/construct for multicore simulation. The testbench codes has to rely on tools for any speedup using multiple cores.
At user level, if it becomes must, incase your Testbench needs lot of CPU time  you need to develop the scheme.
e.g.

1. Build to simple light weight driver with ability to receive /send messages from other running OS process via a) message passing mechanism 2) simple file read/writes
2. Build testbench with ability to send/receive message to other OS processes
3. Run RTL + light weight driver simulation
4. Run Testbench

On multicore machine, you will have (or OS will do for you) one core running RTL another running testbench.